# service worker gives page can't be found while refreshing the page for the pages other than home

Tags: angular5, asp.net-core-2.0, service-worker, angular-universal

I am using asp.net core with angular universal.Below code I used for service worker

```
       services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions
  {
    CacheId = "v=123",
    Strategy = ServiceWorkerStrategy.CacheFingerprinted,
    RoutesToPreCache = "/,/Home/Index, /Shared/_Layout,/Shared/Error,/favicon.ico,/dist/vendor.js,/dist/main-client.js"
    OfflineRoute = "index.html",
  });
```

used WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa;

while reloading the page in offline gives page is not cached error.without reloading its fine for all pages.pls help me.

Comment: Any chance you're using Chrome 67 or 68? Does it work in other browsers? I'm having the same problem except all my pages work *except* the home page... [Here are my details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51833056/fetch-api-inside-service-worker-fails-only-for-the-home-page-when-reloading-it)

Comment: sorry,I can't solve this issue.It is not working in all browsers